# Can OpenGL convert integer pixel data to floating point or UNORM?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glteximage2d

`glTexImage2D` takes `internalFormat` (which specifies number of bits and data type/encoding), `format` (without number of bits and encoding) and `type`.

Is it possible, for example, to let OpenGL convert passed pixel data containing 32 bit integers from format `GL_RGB_INTEGER` and type `GL_INT` to internal format `GL_RGB32F`?

The wiki article https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Format_conversion suggests to me it's possible by stating:

> Pixels specified by the user must be converted between the user-specified format (with format​ and type​) and the internal representation controlled by the image format of the image.

But I wasn't able to read from floating point sampler in shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_INTEGER` pixel transfer formats are *only* to be used for transferring data to integer image formats. You are filling in a floating-point texture, so that doesn't qualify. You should have gotten an OpenGL Error.

Indeed, the very article you linked to spells this out:

> Also, if "_INTEGER" is specified but the image format is not integral, then the transfer fails.

`GL_RGBA32F` is not an integral image format.

If you remove the `_INTEGER` part, then the pixel transfer will "work". OpenGL will assume that the integer data are *normalized* values, and therefore you will get floating-point values on the range [-1, 1]. That is, if you pass a 32-bit integer value of 1, the corresponding floating-point value will be `1/(2^31-1)`, which is a very small number (and thus, almost certainly just 0.0).

If you want OpenGL to *cast* the integer as if by a C cast `(float)1`... well, there's actually no way to do that. You'll just have to convert the data yourself.

Comment: That made it clear. But isn't UNORM on the range [0,1] and not [-1,1]?

Comment: @mak: `GL_INT` is *signed*. Therefore, OpenGL will interpret such values as [signed, normalized integers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Normalized_Integer).